# Не определяется id в class

Tags: kotlin

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой, что ид View которые объявлены не находятся в классе. То есть появляется ошибка
[image: Ошибка]

Но если в введу этот же код например в классе любого фрагмента, все определяется и появляется подсказка Import
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все дело в правильных импортах: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение данного вопроса:
Добавление в Gradle APP

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

Возможно помогу данным ответом.